# Alternative for DOMDocument()

Tags: php, ini

i am using DOMDocument() to include RSS feed in my code. However i get this error:

URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration

and thats because my server doesnt allow me either to modify the php.ini file or to set allow_url_fopen to ON.

Is there a workaround for this? This is my full code:

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('rss.php');

$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
$item = array (
'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
);
array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 5;
echo '<table>';
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
 $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
 $link = $feed[$x]['link'];

 echo <<<EOF
 <tr>
  <td><a href="$link"><b>$title</b></a></td>
 </tr>
EOF;
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Unless **`allow_url_fopen`** is set to ON , you will not be able to access remote URLs.

Comment: Its actually kinda odd because the RSS feed is on my same server...

Comment: loading a local file with DOM does not need URL file-access. there must be someting else wrong. but just as a random shot try $dom->loadXml(file_get_content('rss.php')). Also note that the PHP inside that rss.php will not get executed when you load it locally, so this might all be not what you are looking for anyway.

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work. It says Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Start tag expected, '<' not found which is crazy, because if i upload the same script above to another server it loads fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, i solved it myself.

```
<?php

$k = 'rss.php';
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $k);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $rss = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($rss, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

    $feed = array();
    foreach($xml->channel->item as $item){
     $item = array (
     'title' => $item->title,
     'desc' => $item->description,
     'link' => $item->link,
     'date' => $item->pubDate,
     );
     array_push($feed, $item);
    }
$limit = 5;
echo '<table>';
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
 $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
 $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
 echo <<<EOF
 <tr>
  <td><a href="$link"><b>$title</b></a></td>
 </tr>
EOF;
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cURL commands. You really should be using this for server to server interactions rather than trying to pass URL's to constructors anyways.

Here is cURL documentation - https://www.php.net/curl

I also have a simple cURL based REST client you can feel free to use - https://github.com/mikecbrant/php-rest-client

Basically, all you are looking to do is use cURL to retrieve the remote content instead of trying to open it directly using fopen wrapper. Once you retrieve the content then you pass it in to DOMDocument.

Comment: I added my full code. Please check it out. I have no idea how to conver that into curl.

Comment: @CainNuke You would simply call $rss->load($content) where $content contains the content of rss.php as retrieved via cURL. The rest of your code doesn't need to change. Read the cURL documentation, or look for other posts on SO about cURL. I am not going to write the whole thing for you.

Comment: I didn't see any URL in OP's code, so using cURL shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Jack yes likely he can just read the content from the local file.  The actual code had not been provided when original answer was given.

Comment: When i do that, i get these errors: 

Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Start tag expected, '<' not found 

which is crazy, because if i upload the same script above to another server it loads fine.